# yii 2.0 ActiveRecord update doesn't work

Tags: activerecord, yii2, updatemodel

I'm a begginer in Yii 2. I'm trying a simple user update, with activerecord, but the update() method doesn't do anything. The update() return back with "true", always "success", but the DB record didn't change.

Controller:

```
use app\models\Users;

.....

$userId = 1;
foreach ($array as $value) {
   $user = Users::findOne($userId);
   //$user->ramount = ($user->ramount + $value->ramunt);
   $user->ramount = 22;
   if ($user->update() !== false) {
     echo "update successful";
   } else {
     echo "update failed";
   }

   //$user = Users::findOne($userId);
   //$user->updateCounters(['ramount' => 22]);
 }
```

I simplified the update because didn't work. The updateCounters() method works perfectly, but I don't want to use that.

Model

```
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;

class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $username;
    public $ramount;

    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'User ID',
            'username' => 'Your name',
            'email' => 'Your email address',
            'ramount' => 'Resources',
        ];
    }

    public static function tableName() {
        return 'users';
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['username'], 'string', 'max'=>60],
            [['email'], 'string', 'max'=>120],
            [['ramount'],'number','max'=>999999],
        ];
    }
}
```

No error in apache log, no error in yii runtime log. Thx all tips

Comment: you are using same `$userid` for update record , so basically you are updating  same record again and again.

Comment: Yes, but I want that. The foreach will be give diferent value. I simplified the update because doesn't work. If work once I will be happy. But update no touch the record. Stay "null", stay 1.

Comment: also you don't have any required field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined in your model class

```
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $username;
    public $ramount;
    ....
}
```

Remove those variables since they override the attributes that ActiveRecord works on.

[Yii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-data) says:

> Note: The Active Record attributes are named after the associated
>   table columns in a case-sensitive manner. Yii automatically defines an
>   attribute in Active Record for every column of the associated table.
>   **You should NOT redeclare any of the attributes**.

Answer (score 0):

Queue your search for the record and set the new value:

```
$userId = 1;
$user = Users::findOne($userId);
$user->ramount = 22;
```

Try using the `save()` method:

```
if ($user->save()) {
  echo "update successful";
} else {
  echo "update failed";
}
```

PD: The return value of save method is boolean(true or false).